# .htaccess mod_rewrite dynamic match with Yii generated urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

I'm trying to use Apache's mod_rewrite module to make dynamically generated urls from a Yii app, which always contain index.php as the router/bootstrap, into static urls through .htaccess available to browse through a web browser.

Example: `localhost/projectname/index.php/commentfeed.xml` is the dynamically generated page, but I want it to be able to be accessed through `localhost/projectname/commentfeed.xml`

Apache version I'm running is: **Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.0** through XAMPP for my development platform. The mod_rewrite module is present and loaded in Apache's httpd.conf file.

My .htaccess in localhost/projectname/ is as follows:

```
#Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
#FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

#Unless an explicit file or directory exists,
#redirect all request to Yii entry script.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, when I try to access commentfeed.xml through my browser without index.php (localhost/projectname/commentfeed.xml) I get a 404 error - Object not found!.

I've looked over the following guides & SO questions: [URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), and [SO: Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) but none of them had explicitly what I was looking for. Also, my apache error log is not reporting anything about the .htaccess file. Any help or guidance towards the correct usage would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the Yii UrlManager that the script name is not required. In your config/main.php file you should have:

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            ...
        ),
    ),
),
```

Make sure you also have a route defined to specify the controller/action that generates the commentfeed.xml file.

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x

Comment: That line is is my /protected/config/main.php and it still is giving me a 404 error, Object not found. I have a sneaking suspicion that it's something to do with xampp or my local apache server. Thanks for the advice tho!

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer to my problem lay in using `<IfModule> ... </IfModule>`. With my setup of XAMPP v3.2.1 and the apache server installed with it, the only lines of code I needed in the .htaccess was simply:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```